# Jquery анимация слайда

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

есть слайдер https://jsfiddle.net/Volchok/eon571w3/3/. Когда начинается анимация при переходе и если переключить слайд, то анимация обрывается. как пофиксить это, хотелось бы, чтобы все происходило плавно

```
    <section class="section section--main"
         style="transition: all 1s ease-out 1s; background-image: url(&quot;../img/slider/Picture8.jpg&quot;);">
  <div class="section__content section__content--main">
    <div class="section__slider-arrow section__slider-arrow--left"></div>
    <div class="section__content-container">
      <div class="section__dot-container">
        <div class="section__dot section__dot--active" data-id="0"></div>
        <div class="section__dot" data-id="1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section__slider-arrow section__slider-arrow--right"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

scss

```
   .section {
  &__content {
    max-width: 1322px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;

    &--main {
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
    }
  }

  &__slider-arrow {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: red;

    &--right {
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
  }


  &__dot-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 27px;
  }

  &__dot {
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    margin: 0 2px;
    cursor: pointer;

    &--active {
      background: #84cce4;
      width: 12px;
      height: 12px;
    }
  }
}
```

js

```
let pictures = [
    'https://mirpozitiva.ru/uploads/posts/2017-04/medium/1492620921_06.jpg',
    'https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/0_8eb56_842bba74_XL-640x400.jpg',
    'https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/tmb_145037_6611.jpg'
];
let slideNow = 0;
let slideCount = pictures.length;
let slideInterval = 3000;
let activePucture = pictures[0];

function activeSlider() {
    activePucture = pictures[slideNow];

    $('.section--main').css({
        'transition': '1s ease-out 0.5s',
        'background-image': 'url("' + activePucture + '")',
    });

    $('.section__dot--active').removeClass('section__dot--active');

    let index = '.section__dot[data-id="' + pictures.indexOf(activePucture) + '"';
    $(index).addClass('section__dot--active');
}

function prevSlider() {
    if (slideNow === 0 || slideNow > slideCount) {
        slideNow = slideCount - 1;
    } else {
        slideNow--;
    }

    activeSlider();
}

function nextSlide() {
    console.log(slideNow, slideCount);
    if (slideNow >= slideCount - 1 || slideNow < 0 || slideNow >= slideCount) {
        slideNow = 0;
    } else {
        slideNow++;
    }
    activeSlider();
}

$('.section__slider-arrow--left').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    prevSlider();
});


$('.section__slider-arrow--right').click(function (e) {
    nextSlide();
});

$('.section__dot').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    slideNow = $(this).attr('data-id');
    activePucture = pictures[slideNow];
    activeSlider();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    let dot = $('.section__dot:not(.section__dot--active)');
    for (let i = 2; i < slideCount; i++) {
        dot.clone(true).attr('data-id', i).appendTo('.section__dot-container');
    }

    let switchInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, slideInterval);

    $('.section--main').hover(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        clearInterval(switchInterval);
    },function() {
        switchInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, slideInterval);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал иным способом:

```
    $('.section--main').stop(true,true).fadeTo( 400 , 0.0, function() {
    $('.section--main').css({
        'background-image': 'url("' + activePucture + '")',
    });
});
$('.section--main').fadeTo( 400 , 1);
```